# offset formula for named range to use in chart?

Tags: excel, charts, range, vba

I am trying to use a (dynamic) named range as the source for my chart.
I was hoping to be able to use 1 named range as the source for the chart, but so far, it is not working.

for example: my data range starts in cel A1 and expands one column at a time to the right.
So now the range is A1:E38. tomorrow it is A1:F38 etc.

So I created a named range with this formula and tried to use it as the source for the chart:

`=OFFSET('ontwikkeling punten'!$A$1;0;0;COUNTA('ontwikkeling punten'!$A:$A);COUNTA('ontwikkeling punten'!$2:$2)+1)`

But excel does not accept this a the data source for my chart. When I select the current range, say A1:E38, and create a chart from it, there is no problem at all. Why does excel not accept my dynamic named range as the source for my chart?

Otherwise, I would have to create 38 separate data ranges.

Answer (score 1):

solved. I found that I should not only type the name of the named range in the chart source field, but also the sheet name. 
So instead of typing `=grafiek_punten` I had to type `='ontwikkeling punten'!grafiek_punten`